# __debugbreak() in Apple clang but not vanilla, how to detect

Tags: macos, clang, llvm, built-in

On OSX 10.9.4, XCode/clang 5.1.1, I seem to be able to use the [__debugbreak()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f408b4et.aspx) intrinsic. This tiny program runs fine (and aborts with a trap as expected) when compiled with Apple clang:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("before\n");
    __debugbreak();
    printf("after\n");
    return 0;
}
```

However, doing the same with a Homebrew installed clang 3.4 or 3.5 yields this output:

```
debugbreak.c:5:5: warning: implicit declaration of function '__debugbreak' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    __debugbreak();
    ^
1 warning generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___debugbreak", referenced from:
      _main in debugbreak.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Needless to say, that's a bit annoying. I'd like to use the `__debugbreak()` function when present, and provide an alternative otherwise.

My question is: how do I best detect the presence of `__debugbreak()`? I would very much like to avoid configure-time checks.

- Is it better if I try to detect whether the compiler is Apple clang or vanilla clang? If so, how do I do that?
- Is there another way to detect the presence of a builtin? Various experiments with `__has_extension()` haven't yielded good results up until now.

P.S.: perhaps Apple has included [this commit](https://www.openhub.net/p/clang/commits/211418482) in their codebase. I can't easily see whether/if that's slated for inclusion in mainline clang.

**EDIT**: It seems that the code *is* there, just normally desactivated in vanilla clang: passing `-fms-extensions` enables `__debugbreak()` in vanilla clang. This is suboptimal though, as it provokes warnings in standard headers for some reason.

Comment: in Xcode 6 (clang versioned as 6.0) __debugbreak is no loner available by default..

Comment: @Urkle could you please add a link to some documentation to support your statement? I bumped into it too, but I don't see it in official documentation.